# macOS Sierra slow in calculating on the Storage tab

Tags: macos

After upgrading to macOS Sierra I find that if I do, Apple > About This Mac > Storage, it just remains stuck on the "Calculating..." for a very long time.

[image]

I am pretty sure that this was not the case with OS X El Capitan.

Does anyone else also see the same issue?

Comment: How long is a very long time?

Comment: Mine did this also but the 'Calculating...' message only lasted about 2 minutes, then it displayed the storage correctly.  Looking thru the Apple support site, this is a common issue.  Most people are just letting it finish the first time thru, then it seems to go faster during subsequent views.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is leave the storage window open for a long time, say ten minutes. I am running 10.12.4.